# how to get all user stories and defects linked with milestone via pyral

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I am trying to get all user stories and defect attach with particular milestone in rally and I'm using [pyral](https://pythonhosted.org/pyral/index.html).
I can't find any documentation or any example of it.

Any help will we appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of fetching User Stories using the python toolkit can be found in [this python examples repo](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/rally-python-api-examples/blob/master/examples/n_get_stories.py).

Where you will want to update this code is within the line specifying the query criteria:

```
criterion = '((Iteration.Name contains "Iteration 6")OR(Iteration.Name contains "Iteration 7"))'
```

Instead of specifying an Iteration Name, you will need to provide the milestone _ref like so:

```
criterion = '(Milestones contains "/milestone/12345678")'
```

And then to get all of the Defects, you would run the same query but request 'defect' instead of 'hierarchicalrequirement'

A different approach would be to make a single request and specify type 'artifact' since user stories and defects both inherit from type 'artifact'.